# Why does altering STATIC_URL in Django disrupt ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX

Tags: python, django

Trying to gain some high level clarity on how Django serves (admin) static files.

When altering the **STATIC_URL** setting in Django's settings.py to a new location (I'm serving images from a 3rd party server) it seems to disrupt **ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX** and thus stop the Admin media (css, images, js) from being served.

Why does this happen?  I though **STATIC_URL** and **ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX** should pertain to different parts of the application and not influence eachother.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Django do you use? Before Django 1.4, the STATIC_URL and ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX are indeed different parts. In Django 1.4, ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX is deprecated and STATIC_URL is used solely.

The way you're using to serve corresponding files is important also. You could check the URLs of media files in the admin page: if they are generated correctly but cannot get loaded, it might be caused by mis-configured web server instead of Django itself.

Comment: Thanks - it seems there are some issues with collectstatic when **STATIC_URL** isn't a subset/derivative of **ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX**.  The app is hosted on Heroku who are still on Django 1.3.1 so this should cease to be an issue soon.